# IE9 rendering a Bootstrap layout oddly, and I can't work out why

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

[Update: Problem Solved.]

The problem is with the title section, where I use a `<span3>` with an `<hr>`, then a `<span6>` with the title, then another `<span3>`. It works fine in every browser except IE9 and below. [Edit: it's broke in Firefox too :-( ]

I can't work out why the layout breaks as it does, and being on a Mac, debugging this using a remote VM is pretty tricky. Any ideas?

Screenshots below:

Chrome and other good browsers:
[image: Chrome and other good browsers]

IE9:
[image: IE9]

Comment: @Perfect Dark Thanks for the heads-up. Confirmed over here as well. Think I must've assumed it would work in Firefox as it works in WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be to add `clear: left;` to the first `<span3>`. This doesn't quite seem like an ideal solution, but it works nonetheless.

The way I have done this in my code is:

```
div.row.page-heading:first-child {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, yes - it does work in IE9 - I had accidentally applied the style to the wrong element and was a bit hasty with my comment.